# want to delete the orphan images from a folder

Tags: php, image, server

i have 1000+ static pages. Each page contains 50 images (using img tag). so almost 50k images are in a folder called product_images.
However this folder size is 25 GB containing many orphan images that are not showing in those pages. I want to delete all orphan images which are not showing in those pages.

What is the best way to achieve this task.

Comment: How are orphaned images determined? What have you tried so far? I guess reading/parsing all your static pages, getting all `<img src>` and removing the orphaned ones

Comment: How are the static pages saved? Are they all individual `.php` / `.html` files? Or are they stored in a database?

Comment: the pages are pure .html files. they are not saved in database. We are using a apache server. i have tried writing a php script that scrolls all pages and saves in a database. And then by comparing , the orphan images can be deleted. but could not get success. This is a live page here https://www.indiabazaaronline.com/pages/wedding-stall.html

Comment: actually previously we were using a shopping cart in which deleting a product never deleted its images. these orphan images are those ones only. Now we have moved to a new shopping cart. That huge image folder is 25 Gb and i am sure that actual images are not more than 7-9 GB. So by deleting orphan images we can save almost 20 GB on server